# Sailsjs many-to-many associations using non-transactional save

Tags: many-to-many, associations, sails.js, waterline

I'm happily using the beta v0.10 of Sailsjs and I was worrying about one question regarding many-to-many associations:

Say, Model-A and Model-B have a many-to-many-association via two attributes. The API recommends using the "add"-method to append one existing Model-A-object to a collection of another Model-B-object, followed by a call to the "save"-method of Model-B, to make the change persistant. This works as expected, but the documentation also mentions the following about the save-method:

"This is an instance method. Currently, instance methods ARE NOT TRANSACTIONAL. Because of this, it is recommended that you use the equivalent model method instead."

But unfortunately, a call to Model-B-update does not persist the changes in the collections in a many-to-many relationship.
As I am NOT an expert in databases, I am insecure if this is a bug, a feature or a misunderstanding on my side. 
Any suggestions greatly welcome!

Ben

Edit: here is a more detailed description of my issue:

Say, we have two models, **User** and **Group**:

```
/**
* User.js
*

module.exports = {
  attributes: {

    [...]

    memberOfGroups: {
      collection: 'group',
      via: 'members'
  }
};


/**  
* Group.js
*

module.exports = {
  attributes: {

    [...]

    members:
    {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'memberOfGroups',
      dominant: true
    }
  }
};
```

As you can see, there is a many-to-many association between these two models. 
Assume, there are two instances, one of each model. One called **aliceUser**, the other **publicGroup**. We want to add **aliceUser** as a member to **publicGroup**.

When I do

```
publicGroup.members.add(aliceUser.id);
publicGroup.save(function(err, saved) { ... });
```

I get the expected results, **aliceUser** is becoming a member of the **publicGroup**:

```
{
    "members": [
        {
            "email": "alice@cc.com",
            "name": "alice",
            "id": 4,
            "createdAt": "2014-06-23T22:20:01.967Z",
            "updatedAt": "2014-06-23T22:20:01.967Z"
        }
    ],
    "name": "public",
    "createdAt": "2014-06-23T22:19:57.489Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-06-23T22:20:01.983Z",
    "id": 1
}
```

Now this is all satisfactory, but the docu states about the save-method, that it is not transactional, possibly leaving me a user and a group getting out of sync. The docu continues:

> Because of this, it is recommended that you use the equivalent model method instead.

To be honest, I'm not hundred percent sure, what they mean, I guessed the sails team was referring to using the **Group.update()** method.

But if I do

```
publicGroup.members.add(aliceUser.id); /*same as before*/
Group.update(publicGroup.id, publicGroup, function(err, updated) {
   [...]
});
```

**aliceUser** is not appended as a member of **publicGroup**:

```
{
    "members": [],
    "name": "public",
    "createdAt": "2014-06-23T22:19:57.489Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-06-23T22:20:01.983Z",
    "id": 1
}
```

Hopefully, this explains my current problem in greater detail. If you need further information, please tell me so. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Transactional is a database think and mean:
- If you have a update in a Database with more than one table the database-software do a automatically rollback if one part of the update dont work.

Thats useful for bank accounts for example. To transfer money from one bank account to another you have to updates 2 items (update bank account 1 set money = money -100 && update bank account 2 set money = money +100). If one of the updates failed, the database do a rollback (so the money dont disappear).

Read more at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

For Waterline (the orm of sails) this mean: If you want to make databaseupdates that are transactional you have to use query() or native()-methods.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried to use query-methods: 
Say I have a model  
`User:  
attributes: {  
memberOfGroups: {  
collection: 'group',  
via: 'members'  
}  
}`  

and a model  
`Group:  
attributes: {  
members: {  
collection: 'user',  
via: 'memberOfGroups',  
dominant: true  
},  
}`  

and two instances aliceUser, publicGroup. I did   `publicGroup.members.add(aliceUser.id);` Now `publicGroup.save(...)` is working (non-transactional), but `Group.update(publicGroup.id, ...)` is not (supposed to be transactional). Maybe I'm using update wrong?

Comment: can you please put the hole code as edit in your question in format it? Also please describe the issue further (what did you expect, what actually happened)?

Comment: I edited my original question, thank you for taking your time